# Есть ли возможность запускать тесты по очереди в C++ при работе с gtest?

Tags: c++, gtest

Мне необходимо написать тесты для проверки баланса AVL деревьев при поворотах/добавлении новых элементов и тд в C++, используя gtest. Единственное решение, которое я вижу - запускать тесты по порядку, и между ними менять структуру дерева, но не могу найти функции для запуска определённых тестов, везде написано только про RUN_ALL_TESTS(), который мне не подходит. Существует ли такая функция, или может можно использовать какой-то другой подход? Ниже код с объявлением структуры дерева и одним тестом

```
TEST(TreeTest,Positive){
    ASSERT_EQ(1, bfactor(tree));
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    node root(0);
    node* tree = &root;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    tree = Insert(tree,i);
    }
    tree = Remove(tree,6);
    Print(tree);
    cout<<bfactor(tree);
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: gtest и так запускает тесты по очереди... А приведенный код мало похож на тесты, и вообще не работоспособен.

Comment: это файл с одним тестом. вопрос в том, можно ли мне изменять структуру дерева между ними, и если да, то как это делать, если gtest запускает все тесты после run_all_tests()

Comment: Все изменения  дерева должны быть ВНУТРИ теста. Тесты должны быть написаны таким образом чтобы сохранять работоспособность и корректность результатов независимо от порядка вызова. main свой писать вообще не нужно. В gtest есть готовая реализация.

Comment: понял. спасибо!